# How do I get a calculated measure to be effected by on page filters in power bi?

Tags: powerbi, dax

I am trying to get a max time stamp on some audit data and I want the end user of the power bi to filter dates and then have max be recalculated based on the user's filtering.

Currently this DAX code:

```
isMax = IF(
    CALCULATE(
        
        MAX('table'[AUDIT_TIME] ) ,

ALLEXCEPT('table','table'[OBJECT_ID], 'table'[VALUE] ) 

)=MAX('table'[VALUE])
                   ,1,0
                  )
```

works to get the max grouped by `OBJECT_ID` and `VALUE`, but as soon as I filter the max `AUDIT_TIME` or group on the page a new  `isMAx = 1` is not generated.